# Newbie Alert: How Do I Determine How Much Storage I'm Using in an Oracle 11g Database?

Tags: oracle11g, storage

Techies--

I am migrating an Oracle 11g database to an MS SQL Server 2012 instance. Before I begin the actual physical copy of data from 11g to MSSQL, how do I determine what kind of space I'll need to set aside? In Oracle SQL Developer I was able to find the Statistics tab while in a SQL session. I see that this tab may give me some of the high-level/rough idea version of what I'm looking for--however, I have several hundred tables, so this approach doesn't seem practical.  Is there a way to issue a sql statement, or execute an existing stored proc to determine how much physical space will be needed to contain this data?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few queries that I keep on my hand and are useful for this exercise

## find out tablespaces and the space they use

```
col "Tablespace" for a22
col "Used MB" for 99,999,999
col "Free MB" for 99,999,999
col "Total MB" for 99,999,999

select df.tablespace_name "Tablespace",
totalusedspace "Used MB",
(df.totalspace - tu.totalusedspace) "Free MB",
df.totalspace "Total MB",
round(100 * ( (df.totalspace - tu.totalusedspace)/ df.totalspace))
"Pct. Free"
from
(select tablespace_name,
round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) TotalSpace
from dba_data_files 
group by tablespace_name) df,
(select round(sum(bytes)/(1024*1024)) totalusedspace, tablespace_name
from dba_segments 
group by tablespace_name) tu
where df.tablespace_name = tu.tablespace_name ;
```

## Get storage from table within a tablespace

```
COLUMN TABLE_NAME FORMAT A20
COLUMN TABLESPACE_NAME FORMAT A20

SELECT
SUBSTR(s.segment_name,1,20) TABLE_NAME,
SUBSTR(s.tablespace_name,1,20) TABLESPACE_NAME,
ROUND(DECODE(s.extents, 1, s.initial_extent,
(s.initial_extent + (s.extents-1) * s.next_extent))/1024000,2) ALLOCATED_MB,
ROUND((t.num_rows * t.avg_row_len / 1024000),2) REQUIRED_MB
FROM
dba_segments s,
dba_tables t
WHERE
s.owner = t.owner AND
s.segment_name = t.table_name and
s.tablespace_name = '<yourtablespacename>'
ORDER BY 3 ASC;
```

Comment: Frederic, do I need to be logged in with SYS privileges on the instance?

Comment: Thanks so much for your time Frederic! These statements have been very helpful. Is there anything special that I need to do for the equivalent of SQL Server's transaction log space?